# Is the intersection of dense subsets of a metric space also dense?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

> (a) Show that if $A$ and $B$ are open dense subsets of a metric space $X$, then $A \cap B$ is also dense in $X$.
>
> (b) What happens if we drop the requirement of $A$ and $B$ being open?

i know how to solve part (a). It's just part (b) that I cannot figure out.

Comment: A non-empty subset may be dense and co-dense . A set is co-dense iff its complement is dense.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: What’s a very familiar countable dense subset of $\Bbb R$? Is its complement dense?

Answer (score 2):

For a counterexample, try:
\begin{align*}
X &= \mathbb{R} \\
A &= \mathbb{Q} \\
B &= \mathbb{Q} + \sqrt{2} = \{q + \sqrt{2} \mid q \in \mathbb{Q}\}.
\end{align*}

To show $B$ is dense, try to show that the translation of any dense set in $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e., shift it over by some number, in this case $\sqrt{2}$) is still dense.
Then what is $A \cap B$?

Comment: Or just let $B=\mathbb R$ \ $\mathbb Q.$

Comment: @user254665 That example was already given. This is example is a bit different, the proof of density of $B$ is a little more direct.

Answer (score 1):

For a counter-example for (b), you can think about

$$A=\mathbb Q$$

and

$$B=\mathbb R\setminus \mathbb Q.$$

Both $A$ and $B$ are dense, but $A\cap B=\emptyset.$